# CodeMirror - Overwriting Home/End buttons to work correctly

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm struggling to correct a behaviour with the CodeMirror editor in which a whole paragraph is recognized as a single line within a set of PRE tags. By pressing the HOME or END buttons on the keyboard I either get navigated to the start of the paragraph or end of the paragraph regardless of how many lines that paragraph might span.

On the Editors extraKeys property I overrode the Home button as follows:

```
extraKeys : {
  "Home" : function(instance){
      console.log(instance);
   }
}
```

However, even though I have a paragraph that extends over 15 lines, only a single set of PRE tags are found so according to CodeMirror there is only a single line in the editor.

Does anyone know of a way to bypass this so that the HOME/END buttons work as intended? I have tried the built in "goLineStart" and "goLineStartSmart" functions but they both go to the start of the paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're meaning that they should take wrapping into account (go the start of the *wrapped* part of the line), you can bind Home and End to the `"goLineLeft"` and `"goLineRight"` commands to get the behavior you want.